# Haskell: Using List Comprehension and reducing x by 1 each list to make x amount of lists

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I'm new to using Haskell I've been spending hours trying to build a simple function where entering a function will turn out like this:

```
makeList 5 == [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5]]
makeList 2 == [[1],[1,2]]
```

No amount of research can really help me figure out how I should iterate my functions 'x' so that I have multiple lists building based on the number I choose, I'm close but that's where I'm stumped, my current code is essentially set up where I can do this if I were to enter makeList 3:

```
makeList 3 = [ [ x | x <- xs ] | xs <- [[1..x-2],[1..x-1],[1..x]] ]
```

prints out:

```
[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: Try to put a `[1..y]` on the left side

Comment: `makeList = tail . inits . enumFromTo 1`

Comment: `[ x | x <- xs ]` is the same as `xs`, so your function is the same as `makeList x = [[1..x-2],[1..x-1],[1..x]]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Prelude> makeList n = [ [1..x] | x <- [1..n] ]
Prelude> makeList 5
[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

Comment: Thank you! That's such an interesting way to be able to iterate but it was exactly what I was trying to figure out!

Comment: @Jace: Notice that it pretty much says what it means: given `n` you want a list of results (`[…]`) for each `x` from 1 to `n` (`[… | x <- [1..n]]`) where each element is a list from 1 to `x` (`[[1..x] | x <- [1..n]`). A pretty good strategy if you’re learning Haskell is to try to phrase a solution in natural language (e.g., English) in a way that’s easy to translate to code—then examine the solution & see how it can be desugared or rephrased. For example, if I wanted to avoid list comprehensions, I might write `makeList = map upto . upto where upto n = [1..n]`

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use explicit recursion.

```
makeList :: Int -> [[Int]]
makeList cap = go 1 where
  go num | num < cap = [1..num]:go (num+1)
         | otherwise = [1..num]:[]
```